# Climbing Stairs Problem ( Access of element in vector )

Tags: vector, stl, c++17, dynamic-programming

Below is a code for the problem of CLIMBING STAIRS https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/

```
class Solution {
public:
    int climbStairs(int n) {
        vector<int> dp(n,0);
        dp[0] = 1;
        dp[1] = 2;
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
            dp[i] = dp[i-2]+dp[i-1];
        }
        return dp[n-1];
    }
};
```

The code gives a RUNTIME ERROR of HEAP BUFFER OVERFLOW.
Looking at the code , if `n==1` the code should return `dp[n-1]` i.e. `dp[0]` ,
but that does not seem to be the case.
I'm guessing the issue maybe related to access of elements in vector.
Can anyone please explain what could be the issue here ??

Answer (score 0):

> if n==1 the code should return dp[n-1] i.e. dp[0] , but that does not seem to be the case.

Yes.

But when `n == 1`, you call

```
dp[1] = 2;
```

so you access the second element when you have only one element.

And what about the case `n <= 0` ?

So, maybe

```
int climbStairs(int n) {
  if ( 0 >= 0 ) {
    return ???;
  } else if ( 1 == n ) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    vector<int> dp(n,0);
    dp[0] = 1;
    dp[1] = 2;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
        dp[i] = dp[i-2]+dp[i-1];
    }
    return dp[n-1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem states the constraints are

> `1 <= n <= 45`

You're going out of range when `n` is 1 (i.e. you only have `dp[0]` that scenario)